# How to retrieve SQL Server RAISERROR (or PRINT) messages?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I'm trying to get the warning message from SQL Server's Raiserror in python with PyODBC.

The severity is low on purpose, because it acts as a printing functionality, but it doesn't have to wait until the query is done before printing.

The output I expect would be something like:

```
*Test Message*
|col1|
|:-|
|1|
```

Here's my code:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=ECH-DWPROD02;DATABASE=Test;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SET NOCOUNT ON; RAISERROR('Test Message',0,1) WITH NOWAIT; select 1 as col1")
cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Erm `PRINT` and `RAISERROR` is not a resultset, looks like you need `cursor.messages`?? https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#messages

Comment: Yes this is exactly the attribute I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Moral of the story: read the documentation first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Cursor.messages](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#messages) is a fairly recent addition to pyodbc (v4.0.31 – July 2021). It allows us to retrieve messages emitted from SQL Server stored procedures *et al.* via PRINT and RAISERROR.

Note that such messages constitute a "result" from the server so if they are returned then one must call `.nextset()` to retrieve additional results, otherwise a "Previous SQL was not a query." error will occur:

```py
crsr.execute("""\
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
RAISERROR('Test Message',0,1) WITH NOWAIT; 
select 1 as col1
""")
print(crsr.messages)
# [('[01000] (50000)', '[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Test Message')]
crsr.nextset()  # required before .fetchall()
print(crsr.fetchall())
# [(1, )]
```

Comment: Thanks!! This comment was very timely and helped with debugging problem I was having. My version was one lower than the required one and I would not have know about this but for your comment.

Comment: This was extremely helpful to me when debugging some SQL statements I was executing via pyodbc