# Capture output from SQL server PRINT statement with Python

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

Can I capture the output from SQL server PRINT statements called from Python with SQLAlchemy? For background, I am building my client application in Python to connect to a MSSQL server, run stored procedures that emit PRINT statements (an existing codebase), then show some information about progress during a long-running operation or at least log the messages.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[BigCalculation]
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    PRINT 'Inserting costs and benefits ... Message 1'
    BEGIN
    -- query1
    END
    PRINT 'Inserting costs and benefits ... Message 2'
    BEGIN
    -- query2
    END
    PRINT 'Done with big calculation'
```

According to previous questions and Transact-SQL documentation, in order to capture the output from a PRINT statement, a client can listen for InfoMessage events. The example is in .NET, and I want to use python.

- [Capture Stored Procedure print output in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1880507/15796661)
- [InfoMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

To start, I am connecting to my MSSQL database with sqlalchemy and pyodbc. I prefer SQLAlchemy because it makes code easy to write and understand.

```python
import sqlalchemy
import pyodbc
print(sqlalchemy.__version__)
print(pyodbc.version)
import urllib
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
                                 r"SERVER=LAPPY\SQLEXPRESS;"
                                 "DATABASE=MY_OLD_DATABASE;"
                                 "Trusted_Connection=yes")
my_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))
my_engine
```

Output:

```
2.0.20
4.0.39
Engine(mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=DRIVER%3D%7BODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server%7D%3BSERVER%3DLAPPY%5CSQLEXPRESS%3BDATABASE%3DMY_OLD_DATABASE%3BTrusted_Connection%3Dyes)
```

### Attempt 1.

With SQLAlchemy, I can [turn on logging](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#dbengine-logging), but I can't find a logging message that includes the output of the PRINT statement.

```python
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger("sqlalchemy.engine").setLevel(logging.INFO)
with my_engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(text("PRINT 'hello'"))
```

Output:

```
2023-08-31 09:43:09,004 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
2023-08-31 09:43:09,005 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine PRINT 'hello'
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:PRINT 'hello'
2023-08-31 09:43:09,005 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 7142s ago] ()
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[cached since 7142s ago] ()
2023-08-31 09:43:09,007 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:COMMIT
```

### Attempt 2.

With SQLAlchemy, I can [listen for events](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/event.html#sqlalchemy.event.listen), but asking to listen for InfoMessage raises InvalidRequestError.

```python
from sqlalchemy.event import listen

def mylistener(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

listen(engine, 'INFOMESSAGE', mylistener)
#listen(engine, 'infomessage', mylistener)
#listen(engine, 'InfoMessage', mylistener)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(text("PRINT 'hello'"))
```

Output:

```python
InvalidRequestError: No such event 'INFOMESSAGE' for target 'Engine(mssql+pyodbc:///...)'
```

### Attempt 3.

With [DBAPI optional extensions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#optional-db-api-extensions), the raw DBAPI connection might offer Connection.messages or Cursor.messages attributes. But with the pyodbc driver (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68912086/how-to-retrieve-sql-server-raiserror-or-print-messages)), it looks like only the raw cursor is working to capture messages, so I can't get PRINT messages from queries executed through the SQLAlchemy connection wrapper.

```python
with engine.begin() as conn:
    # Execute a "normal" sqlalchemy query
    conn.execute(text("PRINT 'hello1'"))

    # Execute a query on a cursor from the raw connection
    connection = conn.connection
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    print(connection)
    print(cursor)
    cursor.execute("PRINT 'hello2'")

    # Look for messages
    for m in cursor.messages:
        print(m)
    for m in connection.messages:
        print(m)
```

Output:

```
<sqlalchemy.pool.base._ConnectionFairy object at 0x0000019AC6D2D660>
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x0000019AC89CE930>
('[01000] (0)', '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]hello2')
AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Connection' object has no attribute 'messages'
```

So, what is the best approach? Are there any other options?

#### Edit

The behavior is similar for RAISERROR statements, the only difference being the timing. Here is a sample.

```py
import time
def get_result_and_messages(cursor):
    from datetime import datetime
    print(datetime.utcnow())
    for m in cursor.messages:
        print(m)
    try:
        print(cursor.fetchall())
    except pyodbc.ProgrammingError:
        pass

with engine.begin() as conn:
    # Execute a "normal" sqlalchemy query
    conn.execute(text("PRINT 'hello1'"))
    
    # Execute a query on a cursor from the raw connection
    connection = conn.connection
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""
        PRINT 'hello2';
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
        RAISERROR('hello3',0,1) WITH NOWAIT;
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
        SELECT 'hello4';
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
        PRINT 'hello5';
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
        """)
    print(get_result_and_messages(cursor))
    while cursor.nextset():
        print(get_result_and_messages(cursor))
```

Output:

```
2023-08-31 21:59:28.971460
('[01000] (0)', '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]hello2')
None
2023-08-31 21:59:29.976399
('[01000] (50000)', '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]hello3')
None
2023-08-31 21:59:58.987831
[('hello4',)]
None
2023-08-31 21:59:58.988891
('[01000] (0)', '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]hello5')
None
```